# How to set vmarg on ant build?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant

When I try to run jdoexamples in appengine sdk I get an error. There is a workaround(-Dappengine.user.timezone.impl=UTC), which works when I set it on eclipse. But how could I do the same when I build it with ant?
Here is the error output from ant build:

```
runserver:
 [java] java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to restore the previous TimeZone
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:228)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.start(DevAppServerImpl.java:164)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain$StartAction.apply(DevAppServerMain.java:164)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.util.Parser$ParseResult.applyArgs(Parser.java:48)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.<init>(DevAppServerMain.java:113)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerMain.main(DevAppServerMain.java:89)
 [java] Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldException: defaultZoneTL
 [java]     at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredField(Class.java:1882)
 [java]     at com.google.appengine.tools.development.DevAppServerImpl.restoreLocalTimeZone(DevAppServerImpl.java:222)
 [java]     ... 5 more
```

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 4 seconds

Comment: set in environment => export ANT_OPTS=-Dfile.encoding=utf-8

Answer (score 0):

Another option is to set the system property from within your build.xml file using the [sysproperty attribute](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html) of the java task:

```
 <java classname="test.Main" >
    <sysproperty key="appengine.user.timezone.impl" value="UTC"/>
  </java>
```

Comment: where should I put it? I just put it after property tag but it didn't help.